# If $M\neq 0$ is any subset of a vector space $X$, show that span $M$ is a subspace of $X$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

**If $M\neq 0$ is any subset of a vector space $X$, show that span $M$ is a
subspace of $X$.**

1. $0\in \text{ span } M$ since $M\neq 0$ then $a\in M$ and since $0$ is a scalar then $(a)(0)=0\in M$.
2. If $x,y \in M$ then $x+y\in M$ by definition of span $M$
3. If $x\in M$ and $c$ is a scalar, then $cx\in M$ by definition of span $M$.

Is this reasoning right? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your definition of span?

Comment: @EricWofsey 
span $M$ is the set of all possible linear combinations of elements of $M$, am I right?

Comment: I'm asking you: there are multiple possible definitions, and whether your proof is complete may depend on what definition you are starting from.

Comment: @user424241 You didn't refer to that definition in your 2 and 3.

Comment: @EricWofsey I am following the book "introductory functional analysis with applications" by Kreyszing, and they do not explicitly say what is the definition of span, I guess that is what I just said above but I'm not sure.

Comment: @EricWofsey I already found the definition of the book, it is as follows:
 For any nonempty subset $M\subset X$ the set of all linear combinations
of vectors of $M$ is called the span of M, written
span $M$.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is right. The only thing I would comment is that in 1 you write "vector times number", which is fairly unusual: the common way is to write "number times vector".